# ubuntu 14.04 getdeb installation problems

Tags: package-management, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04. Later I tried to install getdeb with
`sudo dpkg -i getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb.`

It got stuck at `Connecting to archive.getdeb.net..`
I aborted this with (ctrl+c) ^C.

Accompanying this there are several errors like frequent  /var/lib/dpkg/lock locks and almost any installation is getting stuck at `Connecting to archive.getdeb.net..`
Please guide me to resolve these problems.

Comment: you can run this command `sudo dpkg -i getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb`even without internet connection.

Comment: That's what I am puzzled. Why is attempting to connect to that site?

Comment: where is `getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb` file located?

Comment: I followed recommendation from http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr to install getdeb and playdeb. First downloading it to say home directory and using above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will be under the `/home/$USER` directory if you alraedy run this `wget http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb` command.

While installing the above `.deb` package, it tries to fetch something from the URL or server (archive.getdeb.net)  because the .deb pacakge is created like that. So connect to the internet before installing the `.deb` package via `dpkg`.

Comment: Even sudo apt-get upgrade is giving the following at the end    `Setting up getdeb-repository (0.1-1~getdeb1) ...
--2014-04-22 16:12:59--  http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key
Resolving archive.getdeb.net (archive.getdeb.net)... 144.76.200.19
Connecting to archive.getdeb.net (archive.getdeb.net)|144.76.200.19|:80...`

Comment: yes, partially installed packages will be  fetched and installed while running `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: But it has stuck there..

Comment: did you connected to the internet? please reply quickly.

Comment: Yes I am connected. `sudo apt-get update` working fine.

Comment: ok try this `sudo rm /home/$USER/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb` and then try `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: if it still shows the error then try `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then run upgrade.

Comment: It's really problematic. Any thing I type with sudo apt-get is directing to `Connecting to archive.getdeb.net (archive.getdeb.net)|144.76.200.19|:80...` and getting stuck there.

Comment: just purge the `getdeb-repository` package via dpkg by running `sudo dpkg -P getdeb-repository`

Comment: Now run upgarde, it will surely works.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Upgrade is not giving any errors now.